# How to create new row using ngFor

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make new row using *ngFor:`<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let user of users">{{user.username}}</div>
</div>`

And then, if  col div`s > 4, i need to create new row.
How can i do it?

Comment: which bootstrap are you using ? Can you show a working sample. It should automatically move the 4th div to next line if its bootstrap 4

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4.

Comment: Then there is no need of creating a new row if 4th element comes, it should wrap automatically

Comment: It doesn't working automatically :( Bootstrap moves next 4 div's down the page, but if i create new row it works correctly.

Comment: Can you show a sample where its not working ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Me helped your link :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create div elements of row class using ngFor, then put the directive in that div.

ngFor will **add** content **including the div it is written in**

So in your example, it will be

> HTML

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of rows;let i = index">
   <div class="col" *ngFor="let col of row;let j = index">
     Row {{i}} Col {{ j }}
   </div>
</div>
```

> TS

```
export class AppComponent  {
  public rows = [
    [1,1,1,1],
    [1,1],
    [1,1,1]
  ]
}
```

Working example : [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-row)

Comment: No, i need something like this: 1t row -> 4 cols; 2d row -> 4 cols; 3d row -> 4 cols

Comment: Those 4 cols for each row are constant or dynamic, like 1st row-> 4 cols, 2nd row->3 cols ... etc @ВладМайлз

Comment: Check my new edit @ВладМайлз